# Device browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, browser-detection

I have built a parallax intro for a clients site - due to the limited budget the animation will only work on higher end browsers, IOS and ie9.

Therefore I need to create a detection script in the sites homepage which will detect the following

IF:

- ie9/ firefox / chrome/ safari - stay on current site
- IOS - Go to IOS version
- Android - Skip to main site
- IE8 and below - skip to main site

I have carried out 'is mobile' detections in the past with PHP - but the above is pretty specific so I'm not sure how to approach it..  The main site is aspx, so I could make the animation page into a aspx page also and use server side detection, or look at Javascript/jquery options or plugins - or a combination of both..?

Can anyone recommend a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code, uses the `navigator` object::

```
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if(navigator.appName == "Netscape"){ //for Firefox, Safari and Chrome
         //do nothing, stay on this page.
         return;
    }
    else if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
        //check for version

        var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null){
          version = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
        }
        if(version >= 9.0){
           //do nothing, stay on this page.
           return;
        }
        else{
           //redirect to the site for lower IE versions.
        }
    }
    else if(ua.match(/Android/i)){
       //code for skipping to Android version
    }
    else if(ua.match(/iPhone/i)){
       //code for skipping to iPhone version
    }
    else if(ua.match(/iPad/i)){
       //code for skipping to iPad version
    }
```

Comment: Cheers for your help Sohel - though I've added alerts for each situation above and Iphone/Ipad/Android alert as the first netscape option

Comment: I nested the if statements for iphone/ipad/android into the netscape if statement and it works a treat!  cheers for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In hopes of not getting into browser detection / feauture detection argument blah blah blah, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html has a good script to handle this

Answer (score 0):

there is a JQuery object `$.browser` which could give you what you need in javascript [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is the api call.

On the Server Side there is a .net Request.Browser object also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx) is the MSDN Api for it.